# FIX Protocol - quickfixJ and versions of FIX

Tags: java, fix-protocol

I am trying to connect to a broker that is using FIX 5.0

I would like to leverage [quickfixj](http://www.quickfixj.org/) for ease and speed of implementation.

Is this going to work? I am assuming 5.0 `extends` (so to speak) the features of prior versions, but I do not want to get too far along and wind up causing more issues than it is worth to use quickfix.

I ask this because the current website says that quickFixJ is okay for versions of fix between 4.0 and 4.4.

Will this still work with 5.0?

Comment: "current website" = your broker or QF/J?  Because QF/J *does* support 5.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many financial institutions use quickfix and it is quite likely that if QuickFix has an issue with version 5.0 the other end has the same issue as it's pretty standard.  BTW You can change the implementation fairly easily, if for example you want to improve the performance. (which is ok, but not great)

Comment: Thanks Peter. Will go ahead and dive in.

Answer (score 0):

quickfixj is generating its classes out of the standard fix dictionaries, so there is no limitation in terms of the framework and from my experience it is very accurate, new releases from 1.5.3 to 1.6 seems to have some issues between 4.x and 5.x compatibility but in general it is quite straight in managing a mix of versions and custom fields, it boils down to the version of reference between the counterparties which applies to every message but essentially on the message level all versions can be woven in / customised